# gcc static library linking vs dynamic linking

Tags: c, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

My build environment is **CentOS 5**. I have a third party library called libcunit. I installed it with autotools and it generates both `libcunit.a` and `libcunit.so`. I have my own application that links with a bunch of shared libraries. `libcunit.a` is in the current directory and `libcunit.so` and other shared libraries are in `/usr/local/lib/`. When I compile like:

```
gcc -o test test.c -L. libcunit.a -L/usr/local/lib -labc -lyz
```

I get a linkage error:

```
libcunit.a(Util.o): In function `CU_trim_left':
Util.c:(.text+0x346): undefined reference to `__ctype_b'
libcunit.a(Util.o): In function `CU_trim_right':
Util.c:(.text+0x3fd): undefined reference to `__ctype_b'
```

But when I compile with `.so` like:

```
gcc -o test test.c -L/usr/local/lib -lcunit -labc -lyz
```

it compiles fine and runs fine too.

Why is it giving error when linked statically with `libcunit.a`?

Answer (score 7):

> Why is it giving error when linked statically with `libcunit.a`

The problem is that your `libcunit.a` was built on an ancient Linux system, and depends on symbols which have been *removed* from `libc` (these symbols were used in `glibc-2.2`, and were removed from `glibc-2.3` over 10 years ago). More exactly, these symbols have been `hidden`. They are made available for dynamic linking to old binaries (such as `libcunit.so`) but no new code can statically link to them (you can't create a new executable or shared library that references them).

You can observe this like so:

```
readelf -Ws /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | egrep '\W__ctype_b\W'
   769: 00000000003b9130     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   31 __ctype_b@GLIBC_2.2.5

readelf -Ws /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a | egrep '\W__ctype_b\W'
# no output
```

Comment: Hi, i am actually compiling cunit project from source (http://cunit.sourceforge.net/). It is not a precompiled binary given to me. I use the autotools to install it.  One more question, libc.a doesn't have ctype_b symbol. But i didn't ask for libc to be statically linked to my test application. So it should be dynamically linked to libc.so.6, right?

Answer (score 3):

Didn't notice that the `libcunit.a` is actually found in your case and the problem with linakge is rather in the CUnit library itself. Employed Russian is absolutely right, and he's not talking about precompiled binary here. We understand that you've built it yourself. However, CUinit itself seems to be relying on the symbol from `glibc` which is not available for static linking anymore. As a result you have only 2 options:

1. File a report to the developers of CUnit about this and ask them to fix it;
2. Use dynamic linking.

Nevertheless, my recommendation about your style of static linkage still applies. `-L.` is in general **bad practice**. CUnit is a 3rd party library and should not be placed into the directory containing source files of your project. It should be rather installed in the same way as the dynamic version, i.e. like you have `libcunit.so` in `/usr/local/lib`. If you'd supply `prefix` to Autotools on the configure stage of CUnit, then Autotools would install everything properly. So if you want to link statically with CUnit, consider doing it in the following form:

```
gcc -o test test.c -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lcunit -Wl,-Bdynamic -labc -lyz
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect and the problem has *nothing* to do with library ordering.

Comment: @Employed Russian: Where do you see my answer to be addressing the problem of _"library ordering"_? The proposed command line is just a copy-paste of OP's command line with some edited/added flags, but not changed linkage order.

Comment: You don't need `-Wl,-Bstatic` if you list `libcunit.a` directly (as OP did).