# Compiling C program that uses a library

Tags: c, linker, autotools

I've made a C program that uses [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) to extract some data from audio files.

What possibilities are there to make the program as portable as possible, preferably without requiring root access when installing?

Libsndfile is not available at the target machines, so i need to somehow package it with my program. Is there a way to statically link the library? I've also looked at some Autotools tutorials, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

I can compile without a hitch on my dev machine, where I installed the libraries using the package manager: `apt-get install libsnfile1-dev`

The makefile is very simple:

```
CFLAGS=-std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -g
CLIBS= -lsndfile -lm
BIN=audiodecode
CC=gcc

MAIN=main.o

FILES=

OBJS=$(FILES) $(MAIN)

.PHONY: all
all: clean $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $(OBJS) $(CLIBS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o $(BIN)
```

Comment: You didn't say -- I'm guessing you're on Linux?
In any case, I think the answers at right under Related are what you're looking for... eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027854/gcc-static-library-linking-vs-dynamic-linking or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181154/linking-gsl-or-other-library-statically-into-a-shared-library

Comment: In a nutshell, if you do not want to distribute the shared library, then any function call you use out of the shared library, will have to be created and defined locally (i.e. in your executable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of packages bundle their dependencies. Examples: rsync (contains a bundled libpopt), gnupg (contains a bundled libz). Other dependencies commonly bundled are gettext or glib.
For inspiration look at how these popular open source projects do it.

Put the content of http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/files/libsndfile-1.0.25.tar.gz into a subdir and add apropriate rules to build the the subdir first.

Untested sample code: 
    OBJS += libsndfile/libsndfile.a

```
libsndfile/libsndfile.a:
       cd libsdndfile && ./configure --enable-static && $(MAKE)
```

For Bonus points add a configure script, that check if the system has already installed libsndfile and link to it dynamically.